# Duplicate Global state store directories

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a kafka stream processing application that uses spring-cloud-stream libraries. This application leverages 3 application.id values to listen to 3 topics. For 2 of these input topics, after processing the data, I push the messages onto respective output topics, which I then use to create GlobalKTables as follows:

```
                streamsBuilder.globalTable(firstSSTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()),
                        Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                                as("ss-1")
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())

                                .withValueSerde(Serdes.String()));


                streamsBuilder.globalTable(secondSSTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()),
                        Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                                as("ss-2")
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())

                                .withValueSerde(Serdes.String()));
```

So, the question is, what application.id does it use to consume data from "firstSSTopic" and "secondSSTopic"? Or is it just the GlobalStreamThread as a standalone consumer without any group? When I check the default state directory (tmp/kafka-streams), I can see the sst and log files for both the global state stores under all the 3 application.id directories. How can i avoid this? As this would take 3X disk space and could potentially lead to the storage getting filled quickly.

Comment: Why are you using `GlobalKTable`? You cannot avoid it (under all the 3 application.id directories). this is how the `GlobalKTable` works (it's normal behavior and depends on the very essence of GlobalKTable)

Comment: The reason why I am using GlobalKTable is that I want to have data from all the partitions stored in all the app instances. I figured, it would be replicated across multiple instances of the app, but couldn't understand why it would persist the same data within the same app instance at multiple places, i.e. for each application.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GlobalKTable`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/GlobalKTable.html) can only be used as right-hand side input for stream-table joins.

> but couldn't understand why it would persist the same data within the same app instance at multiple places

This provides the ability to perform joins with `KStream` without having to repartition the input stream.

> How can i avoid this?

You cannot avoid this using `GlobalKTable`.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thanks!